# extract android animation frames

Tags: android, animation

Is it possible to extract android xml animation frames ?
For example I applied an xml android animation on textview, flying from top to bottom for 500 ms, Is it possible to extract these animation frames to Bitmap and then convert them to a movie ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you just want a way to record the animation happening on a device?

Comment: Yes, I want to record the animation frames

Comment: Yes, I want to record the animation frames

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this:

**screenrecord utility**

On `KITKAT` and up, a utility is included called `screenrecord`. This will only work on a physical device, the emulator **does not** include the `screenrecord` utility.

From your terminal run `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/yourfilename.mp4`, this will start recording the screen. Now you can launch your app and run the animation and it will be recorded. To stop recording, from your terminal press `ctrl-c`.

The video will be stored in the `/sdcard` directory, so you'll need to use `adb` to pull it from the device. Continuing with the above example, the command to pull the file off the device would be `adb pull /sdcard/yourfilename.mp4 ~/Desktop`.

**Telecine**

The second option would be to use `Telecine`. It is an free app you can download and run on your device. Here is a [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jakewharton.telecine&hl=en) to it.